# best way to select column based on current date (Excel VBA)

Tags: excel, vba, date

I have a small tracker program I am building in Excel VBA. I have a userform that I keep up throughout the day, inputting my tasks/data via an 'Add' button. At the end of the day, I click the 'Post' button, and it saves the data to my worksheets where appropriate.

Thought I had it finished and working correctly, but now apparently my sub to **select the correct column based on the day's date** is not working, and I'm not sure why, as it had been working perfectly throughout development.

This piece is vital, as my other functions to post the day's data rely on this. I've read a lot of other posts about how to do this (selecting a column based on current date), but none have explained why mine isn't working. Trying to become a better coder, and not just a copy/paste coder, so thought I would try asking here. Copy/Paste usually gets me into these messes, where I'm using tools/functions that work, but I don't know why, and can't troubleshoot/debug on my own.

My total project involves 5 worksheets, but this sub should only involve 2 of them. "Tasks" and "Data Tracker", both of which have a row of dates.

Below is the sub in question.

```
Public Sub currentDate()
'sub to assign current date to global values

     Set rng - Range("H2:HZ2")
     Set myDate = rng.Find(What:=Int(Date), LookIn:=xlFormulas)

End Sub
```

If I step through it, Date is pulling the correct date, and xlFormulas shows a value of -4123 (I don't even know if that matters)..

(UPDATE) so apparently, this morning, it decided to work perfectly. *facepalm* Any clues?

(UPDATE) so, per usual, I try adding features as I fix something else, so this took a bit more researching to solve, but @Super-Symmetry pointed me in the right direction! As noted in a comment down below, I changed my date headers in the two sheets to be more of a  "start date + n" situation. Although his suggestion of using xlValue instead of xlFormula was on the right track, Find. was still having trouble with date vs serial. Ultimately this is what I got to work:

```
Public Sub currentDate()
'sub to assign current date to global values

     'load the date range
     Set rng = Worksheets("Tasks").Range("H2:HZ2")
     'load the values in the range
     dateArray = Range("H2:HZ2").Value
     Dim day As Variant 'object to load dateArray
     Dim loc As Integer 'matches date with cell location

     'converting the date to serial
     For Each day In dateArray
          day = CLng(day)
          loc = loc + 1
          If day = Date Then 'we found the right column
               Set myDate = rng(loc)
               'selects the correct cell
               If ActiveSheet.name = "Data Tracker" Then 'adjust the row
                    Cells(myDate.Row + 3, myDate.Column).Select
               Else 'sheet must be Tasks
                    Cells(myDate.Row + 2, myDate.Column).Select
               End If
               Exit Sub
           End If
      Next
End Sub
```

It's not elegant, but it works.. please feel free to educate me if you have any cleaner ways to do this!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing `Int(Date)` to `CLng(Date)`

```vb
Public Sub currentDate()
'sub to assign current date to global values
    Dim rng As Range, myDate As Range
    
    Set rng = Range("H2:HZ2")
    Set myDate = rng.Find(What:=CLng(Date), LookIn:=xlValues)

End Sub
```

Comment: so unfortunately I'm still having the same issue..  it appears that myDate gets set to 'Nothing'.  (I should note that I have tried dim'ing myDate as a Range and as a Variant) This 'Nothing' then causes the tracker to crash when, later on, I try to run this code:
 `With wsTasks.Cells(myDate.row + (tskLoc(i) - 2), myDate.column)`

Comment: 1) In the worksheet are the dates stored as constants or results of formulae? If they are formulae, you need to change `LookIn:=xlFormulas` to `LookIn:=xlValues`. 2) Are the dates pure dates or do they have time as well? In other words are they integers or do they have decimal (fraction) parts?

Comment: So, I changed my date "headers" to be  startDate + w20 (a value I set, so that I can easily reset the range, plus the value in a row of increasing numbers), and now even my conditional formatting formula (to highlight the day's column) is throwing a "Object variable or With block variable not set". 

I changed the formula to this:
`
 Set rng = Range("H2:HZ2")
 Set myDate = rng.Find(What:=CLng(Date), LookIn:=xlFormulas)
 Cells(myDate.row+2, myDate.Column.Select)`